# Create empty object from enum typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I have some models like this

```
export class ExpertOperational {
  comment: string;
  outOfService: Date;
  score: string;
  supplierNumber: string;
  useSlots: boolean;
  workingDay: ExpertWorkingDay[] = [];
  workSpeedSurvey: string;
  workSpeedVisit: string;
}

export class ExpertWorkingDay {
  constructor(
    public weekDay: WeekDays,
    public operationalAM: ExpertWorkingHours,
    public operationalPM: ExpertWorkingHours
  ) {}
}

export enum WeekDays {
  MONDAY = 'MONDAY',
  TUESDAY = 'TUESDAY',
  WEDNESDAY = 'WEDNESDAY',
  THURSDAY = 'THURSDAY',
  FRIDAY = 'FRIDAY',
  SATURDAY = 'SATURDAY',
  SUNDAY = 'SUNDAY'
}

export class ExpertWorkingHours {
  constructor(
    public fixed: boolean,
    public startTime: string,
    public endTime: string
  ) {}
}
```

What i need is to create empty object from enum and models that will look like this

```
const expert = {
  comment: '',
  outOfService: '',
  score: '',
  supplierNumber: '',
  useSlots: false,
  workingDay: [
    {
      weekDay: 'MONDAY',
      operationalAM: {
        fixed: false,
        startTime: '',
        endTime: ''
      },
      operationalPM: {
        fixed: false,
        startTime: '',
        endTime: ''
      }
    },
    {
      weekDay: 'TUESDAY',
      operationalAM: {
        fixed: false,
        startTime: '',
        endTime: ''
      },
      operationalPM: {
        fixed: false,
        startTime: '',
        endTime: ''
      }
    },
    {
      weekDay: 'WEDNESDAY',
      operationalAM: {
        fixed: false,
        startTime: '',
        endTime: ''
      },
      operationalPM: {
        fixed: false,
        startTime: '',
        endTime: ''
      }
    },
    {
      weekDay: 'THURSDAY',
      operationalAM : {
        fixed: false,
        startTime: '',
        endTime: ''
      },
      operationalPM
        : {
        fixed: false,
        startTime: '',
        endTime: ''
      }
    },
    {
      weekDay: 'FRIDAY',
      operationalAM: {
        fixed: false,
        startTime: '',
        endTime: ''
      },
      operationalPM: {
        fixed: false,
        startTime: '',
        endTime: ''
      }
    },
    {
      weekDay: 'SATURDAY',
      operationalAM: {
        fixed: false,
        startTime: '',
        endTime: ''
      },
      operationalPM: {
        fixed: false,
        startTime: '',
        endTime: ''
      }
    }, {
      weekDay: 'SUNDAY',
      operationalAM: {
        fixed: false,
        startTime: '',
        endTime: '',
      },
      operationalPM: {
        fixed: false,
        startTime: '',
        endTime: ''
      }
    }
  ],
  workSpeedSurvey: '',
  workSpeedVisit: ''
}
```

**What i need is to create object with empty values from model, i dont need to have data!
I have tried like this but i had no luck**

```
const data: ExpertWorkingDay[] = [];
const workingHours = Object.values(WeekDays);
workingHours.forEach(day => {
  data.push(
    new ExpertWorkingDay(
      WeekDays[day],
      new ExpertWorkingHours(
        fixed: false,
        startTime = '',
        endTime = ''
      ),
      new ExpertWorkingHours(
        fixed: false,
        startTime = '',
        endTime = ''
      )
    )
  );
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm able to create the required result . You can refer : https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ejz8k9

Comment: But you only have MONDAY?

Comment: I just used 'MONDAY' , your day can be anything . If you want the ``day`` to be dynamic , you'll have to use ``WeekDays[day as keyof  WeekDays]``

Comment: Can you please write and aswer that i can accept, thanks

Comment: i have added the answer  :)

Comment: I had provided an answer for this same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393386/creating-object-from-enum-and-several-objects-in-loop/59393823#59393823), did it not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `day` is dynamic , you'll have to specify that `day` is of type `WeekDays` .

to do that , you can use `WeekDays[day as keyof WeekDays]`

The below code will help you out :

```
workingHours.forEach(day => {
  data.push(
    new ExpertWorkingDay(
      WeekDays[day as keyof WeekDays],
      new ExpertWorkingHours(
        false,
        '',
        ''
      ),
      new ExpertWorkingHours(
        false,
        '',
        ''
      )
    )
  );
});
```

I have modified the same example with the problem at hand . Refer [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ejz8k9) .

I have added `workingDays` as `['MONDAY' , 'TUESDAY']` .

**EDIT** :

Since the OP is trying to get the enum keys using `Object.values()` , you don't have to do anything as `Object.values()` will return `Array<WeekDays>`. So set the type of `const workingHours` as `Array<WeekDays>` .

```
const data: ExpertWorkingDay[] = [];
// const workingHours : string[] = Object.keys(WeekDays); //If enum keys
// const workingHours : string[] = ['MONDAY' , 'TUESDAY']; //if day as array
const workingHours : WeekDays[] = Object.values(WeekDays);
workingHours.forEach(day => {
    data.push(
        new ExpertWorkingDay(
            WeekDays[day],
            new ExpertWorkingHours(
                false,
                '',
                ''
            ),
            new ExpertWorkingHours(
                false,
                '',
                ''
            )
        )
    );
});

console.log(data);
```

[image: Type returned for Object.values()]

Comment: I have enum, and not const, that why this WeekDays[day as keyof WeekDays], doens not work :(

Comment: @MiomirDancevic  ,if you end up using ``Object.values(WeekDays)`` ,  the answer would work without ``as keyof Weekdays`` .I have updated the answer .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you don't want the use the hard-coded values of the array instead use the enum.

I have added a sample code, if it helps..

```
const data: ExpertWorkingDay[] = [];
const workingHours = Object.keys(WeekDays);

console.log(workingHours);

workingHours.forEach(day => {
  data.push(
    new ExpertWorkingDay(
      WeekDays[day as keyof WeekDays],
      new ExpertWorkingHours(
        false,
        '',
        ''
      ),
      new ExpertWorkingHours(
        false,
        '',
        ''
      )
    )
  );
});
```

Comment: Conversion of type 'WeekDays' to type 'number | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "m